# Template function with template return type in C++

Tags: c++, templates

Relevant portion of the .h file:

```
template<class T, class W>
T inputValidate( T input, W minVal, W maxVal);
```

Relevant portion of the .cpp file:

```
T inputValidate( T input, W minVal, W maxVal)
{
  if (input < minVal || input > maxVal)
  {
    cout << "Invalid input! Try again: ";
    cin input;
  }

return input;
}
```

I get an error of "error: ‘T’ does not name a type"

Comment: There's a good chance that your next question will be something along the lines of "how come I get an undefined reference error when I include this header and try to use this template in another source file?"  To preemptively answer that, [you almost always need to put the definition of the template in the header file.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12).

Comment: @James: You called it, although it showed up as a comment to an answer, not a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to repeat the template declaration before your function definition:

```
template<class T, class W>
T inputValidate( T input, W minVal, W maxVal)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: now I get:                                                                         undefined reference to `short inputValidate<short, int>(short, int, int)'

Comment: Im not sure what James' Link is saying. I don't understand what I should do.

Comment: @user450632:  If you have a question for someone, you can use `@theirusername` (like `@James`) and they will be notified.  To answer your question:  You have to define the function template in the header file, not in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

You must define the function as:

```
template <class T, class W> T inputValidate(T input, W minVal, W maxVal) {

}
```

Comment: Im not sure what James' Link is saying. I don't understand what I should do.

Comment: @user450632: There are other files where you are including the above header file using #include "validate.h" or something similar. Instead of that, just use #include "validate.cpp".